# Which style item name refers to the marker for the items that are currently not selected in a ListPreference?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-preferences, android-styles

To rephrase my question: What should the XXXX be in the code for the style I use for the dialogs in my preferences?

```
    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bkant</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="XXXX">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

To clarify what I mean: I want to change the empty grey circles to the left of all items that are not "Five minutes" from grey to @color/colorAccent.

[image: this picure]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after trial and error with some of the options Android Studio suggested as autocompletion when I typed "color" where the XXXX was, I found that "colorControlNormal" did that trick:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bkant</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```